# In R, modify a value within a class

Tags: r, class, oop

Maybe I am thinking of R classes as if they were classes in C or Java, but I cannot seem to modify values:

```
test <- function() {

  inc <- function() {
    x <- attr( obj, "x" )
    x <- x + 1
    print(x)
    attr( obj, "x" ) <- x
    return( obj )
  }

  obj <- list(inc=inc)
  attr( obj, "x" ) <- 1
  class(obj) <- c('test')
  return( obj )
}
```

When I run this:

```
> t <- test()
> t <- t$inc()
[1] 2
> t <- t$inc()
[1] 2
```

It is as if the original class object cannot be modified.

Comment: `attr( obj, "x" ) <<- x` does it. See the account example in An Intrduction to R, file R-intro.pdf in your installation of R, [section 10.7 Scope](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope).

Comment: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html for a comprehensive review  of OO in `r`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the lexical scoping mechanism of R to achieve a C or Java like object orientation.
Use `<<-` to assign a value in the parent environment.

A simplified version of your examples is below.

```
test <- function() {
    inc <- function() {
        x <<- x + 1
        print(x)
    }
    x <- 1
    list(inc=inc)
}
obj <- test()
obj$inc()
[1] 2
obj$inc()
[1] 3
```

See also `?refClass-class` for what is called "reference classes" in R.

Comment: That seems like an excellent example of scoping that would find it's way into more R tutorials. Thanks!